# i want to know VC++ 6.0 uses .Net frame work or not?

Tags: c++

i am doubtful about it that vc++6.0 is .Net framework independent or depends on it help required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VC++ 6.0 does *not* depend on .NET. It shipped as part of the last set of Microsoft development tools before the debut of .NET. You can rest assured, though, that even versions of VC++ since then don't bring in .NET by default--they only use .NET if you compile with managed extensions turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ 6.0 (people still use it?) came out in 1998, predating the release of .NET Framework by about four years.  Therefore, it does not .

Comment: Mr. when we have to design an interface independent of .NET framework i think it is good choice

Comment: @moon Not really, when you need to design an Interface independent from .net, then using a 10 year old, unsupported compiler with multiple known standard violations is not a good choice. VC6 is vintage, just like Windows 98. If I wanted a Windows Development tool to write an interface that does not use .net, I would use Visual C++ 2008 (or the 2010 version that comes out in 2 weeks) and create a Win32 project, as these do not use .net. (the .net version of C++ is called C++ CLI, but Visual Studio can still create native Win32 C++ projects)

Comment: I'm trying to understand the down-vote.  Was my answer factually incorrect, irrelevant, or irreverent?

Comment: @moon, using VC6 for any sort of new development is a very _bad_ choice. It wasn't a particularly good compiler when it was current, it's not supported anymore as Michael says, it doesn't know about the newer processors for optimisation purposes etc etc.